# Which rule has priority when multiple routing rules apply for AWS S3 Static Site

Tags: amazon-s3, redirect

I'm looking to [redirect rules for an AWS S3 site](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html#advanced-conditional-redirects). I don't see anywhere in the documentation that states which rules take priority when multiple rules might match.

Let's say I have a configuration like:

```json
[
    {
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "docs/foo"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "foo/"
        }
    },
    {
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "docs/foo/bar"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "bar/"
        }
    }
]
```

Would a request for `docs/foo/bar/baz`, which object would the static site rout to and **why**?

Answer (score 0):

Good question. It is indeed not mentioned in the doc, but after some experiments, it appears that the rule with a smaller index in the array will take the priority. I guess the S3 checks the configuration array by iterating through it in order when a request comes.

In the case of a request with the path `docs/foo/bar/baz`, the first routing rule matches and you are redirected to `foo//bar/baz`.

Hope this helps.